# Remotely deploy projects using NetBeans IDE

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

Trying to configure NetBeans project to use remote Java:

[image]

But When I try to set remote platform to project I get back to default one

[image]

How to tell system to use remote Java?

[image]

If I go to Libraries I don't see Remote platform

[image]

UPD

I have this issue with two NetBeans installation - in Win And Ubuntu machines that connects to the same remote Java.

Answer (score 0):

Restart Netbeans. It woked for me every time when i cant choose Remote Plattform.

Comment: Tried that - not helps.

Comment: I tried it again. Netbeans 8.1 (build 201510222201). If i click Customize in Set Project Configuration, Project Properties window appear. Now i CANT choose remote plattform.
BUT if i right click to project in project explorer, then choose properties, now i can choose remote plattform.